# Extracting several parameters from a VM from Azure through CLI (Code not working)

Tags: azure, azure-cli

I'm trying to gather information about VMs through the CLI in order to get those faster than through the Azure-Portal.
I'm trying to extract the vnet, the subnet and the routing table for the given VM.
But this is my first time using the CLI and my code is not working. I have disabled the login/logout for now and the input of the VM name.

The error occurs at the line `$vnetId = (Get-AzNetworkInterface -Name $vm.Name -ResourceGroupName $vm.ResourceGroupName).IpConfigurations[0].Subnet.Id.Split("/")[-3]`

I'm getting the following error message: "

> Get-AzNetworkInterface : The Resource 'Microsoft.Network/networkInterfaces/vmva2015' under resource group 'RG-REDISPATCHPROD-PROD-001' was not found. For more details please go to
> https://aka.ms/ARMResourceNotFoundFix
> StatusCode: 404
> ReasonPhrase: Not Found
> ErrorCode: ResourceNotFound
> "

I'm fairly out of my depth and looking for help.

```
# Importieren der benötigten Az-Module
Import-Module Az.Accounts
Import-Module Az.Network
Import-Module Az.Compute
Import-Module Az.Resources
Import-Module Az.DesktopVirtualization

# Anmelden bei Azure
    #Connect-AzAccount

# Eingabeaufforderung für den VM-Namen anzeigen
    #$vmName = Read-Host "Geben Sie den Namen der VM ein: "
$vmName = "vmva2015" # Der Name der VM ist hier fest kodiert, für Testzwecke

# Durchsuchen aller Abonnements nach der VM
$subscriptions = Get-AzSubscription
foreach ($subscription in $subscriptions) {
    Set-AzContext $subscription

    # Suchen der VM mit dem angegebenen Namen
    $vm = Get-AzVM -Name $vmName -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
    if ($vm) {
        $resourceGroupName = $vm.ResourceGroupName
        # Die VM wurde gefunden, die benötigten Parameter abrufen
        $vnetId = $vm.NetworkProfile.NetworkInterfaces[0].Id.Split("/")[8]
        $vnet = Get-AzVirtualNetwork -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroupName -Name $vnetId
        $subnetId = $vm.NetworkProfile.NetworkInterfaces[0].Id.Split("/")[10]
        $subnet = Get-AzVirtualNetworkSubnet -Name $subnetId -VirtualNetwork $vnet
        $rtName = $subnet.RouteTable.Id.Split("/")[-1]
        $rt = Get-AzRouteTable -Name $rtName -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroupName

        # Ergebnisse ausgeben
        Write-Host "Name der VM: $($vm.Name)"
        Write-Host "Name des VNet: $($vnet.Name)"
        Write-Host "Name des Subnet: $($subnet.Name)"
        Write-Host "Name der Routing-Tabelle: $($rt.Name)"

        # Das Skript endet, sobald eine VM gefunden wurde
        break
    }
}
```

Best,
Edward

I have tried several internet searches which lead me to different site, but my knowledge is too limited to find an answer (and I have tried for roughly 6–7 hours by now).

Answer (score 0):

Azure Query - List snapshots where the name contains AzureBackup_ and must have the tag “CreatedBy : AzureBackup” , But must have any other tag

I have created a snapshot with the below **name** and **tags**.

**Name:** AzureBackup
**Tags:** CreatedBy: AzureBackup

[image]

> I have referred the the below commands from this [MS
>
> document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/snapshot?view=azure-cli-latest#az-snapshot-list)
> to retrieve the **Snapshot** if the tags match.
>
> ```bash
> $snap= az snapshot list --query
> "[?tags.CreatedBy=='AzureBackup'].name"
> ```

The above command filters snapshots by the **CreatedBy** tag with a value of **AzureBackup** and selects only the **name** field of the snapshots.

**Output:**

[image]

> ```bash
>  $snapshot = az snapshot list --query
> "[?tags.CreatedBy=='AzureBackup' && contains(name, 'AzureBackup')]"
> ```

> Above command referred from this [MS Document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/snapshot?view=azure-cli-latest#az-snapshot-list)

The above command filters snapshots by the **CreatedBy** tag with a value of **AzureBackup** and selects all fields of the snapshots that have `'AzureBackup'` in their name.

**Output:**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this command line?

```
az network vnet show -g MyResourceGroup -n MyVNet && az network route-table show -g MyResourceGroup -n MyRouteTable
```

It will show you all the details you need.

If you need more information, just follow this link:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/network/route-table?view=azure-cli-latest#az-network-route-table-show